# Checkbox checked with PHP form post?

Tags: php, mysql

How do I check a checkbox?

I've tried 1, On, and Yes. That doesn't work. Putting the worked "checked" alone works, but then how do I check with PHP after a form post of the checkbox is checked?

```
<input type="checkbox" class="inputcheckbox" id="newmsg" name=chk[newmsg2] value="1" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A checkbox will only be a successful control if it is checked.

Controls that are not successful are not submitted as data.

Therefore, you can tell if a checkbox is checked by seeing if its value has been submitted.

E.g.

```
if ($_POST['chk']['newmsg2'] == 1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code;

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" class="inputcheckbox" id="newmsg" name=chk[newmsg2] value="1" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
    $check = $_POST['chk']['newmsg2'];
    echo "***$check****"
?>
```

If it is checked $check will show 1.

Comment: nothing is being updated? like you said in your example it should return 1 when checked. I checked the box and submited the form and nothing was saved to the database. the mysql update is correct, I tested it with a forced manual insert and its correct.


this is my form:
<input type="checkbox" class="inputcheckbox" id="newmsg" name=chk[newmsg2] />

and then i did a simiple test php mysql submit

if(!isset($_POST['edit_prefs'])) {   
$mewmsg = $_POST['chk'][newmsg1];  
mysql_query("UPDATE social_members_prefs SET m_newmsg='".$newmsg."' WHERE p_id='".$m_id."'");
}

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" class="inputcheckbox" id="newmsg" name=chk[newmsg2] value="1" <?php if ($_POST['chk']['newmsg2']): ?>checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> />
```